# Executable and DLL/Shared Library in the same binary

Tags: c++, linux, windows, operating-system

Is it possible to create single binary that the operating system can load and run as an executable but which is also possible to dynamically link against?

This will be useful for resource sharing across applications where the client and the server can reside in the same executable (and possibly even share code).

I am interested in Linux as well as Windows

Answer (score 3):

On Windows at least this is not supported. You load modules with `LoadLibrary` and you cannot pass an executable file to `LoadLibrary` and subsequently execute code from that module. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) says:

> LoadLibrary can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file to get a handle that can be used in FindResource or LoadResource. However, do not use LoadLibrary to run an .exe file. Instead, use the CreateProcess function.

The easiest way to achieve what you need is as follows:

- Put all the code for your application into a DLL.
- Export whatever functions you need from that DLL.
- Also export a `main` function, or perhaps `WinMain` if this is a GUI subsystem app.
- Create a trivial executable program that links to your DLL and delegates its main function to that exported by the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, it could answer your question at least under windows.
http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Using_an_exe_as_a_dll.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exe to export symbol links in a lib and link another project (DLL project for instance) to that lib. You can then load the DLL dynamically from the exe itself and everything works. I'm not sure if can use it otherwise like using `LoadLibrary`

Razvan.